# colocar link em uma imagem para ser redirecionado para outro site

Tags: html5

entao galera tenho uma imagem, queria que ao clicar nessa imagem o usuario fosse redirecionado para o link que eu defini,

```
<a href="www.google.com"><img src="img/css3.png" class="media-object  img-responsive img-thumbnail"></a>
```

porem quando clico na imagem aparece pagina nao encontrada

Comment: faltando http:// no link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dentro do seu `href=` coloque `http://www.....` ou apenas `//www....`

Comment: nossa cara brigadao tava arrancando os cabelos ja, detalhe simples e eu me matando aqui para resolve-lo obrigado

Comment: Por nada @FernandoAlcantara, não esqueça de marcar como resposta correta.

Answer (score 6):

O parâmetro *href* da tag *a* aceita tanto links relativos, quanto absolutos.

Da maneira como foi colocado em seu exemplo, entende-se o link como relativo, logo ele readicionará o usuário para:

```
www.seusite.com/suapagina/www.google.com
```

Para que o link seja absoluto deve-se utilizar *//* no inicio, isto é:

```
<a href="//www.google.com"><img src="img/css3.png" class="media-object  img-responsive img-thumbnail"></a>
```

Mais informações na [documentação](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp).